# Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'ef'

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.1 and I have the following on startup:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddUserSecrets();
```

I am using csproj file instead of JSON where I added:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <UserSecretsId>8844d677-223b-4527-a648-387a65933d55</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But when I run the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "InitialCommit"
```

I get the error:

```
An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'ef, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have run into this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/543

The solution is to change your call  `.AddUserSecrets()` to `.AddUserSecrets(Assembly assembly)`

See this announcement about how deprecating project.json required a breaking change to user secrets: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/209

Comment: If you get the error `'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddUserSecrets'`, make sure you add this missing Nuget package: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also. My solution was to install the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked for me when I changed a version of package in .csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
```

to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
```